# System causing high Disk Usage across network

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-10, windows-8

This question has been asked numerous times on this site, but usually it refers to a specific computer. My problem is broader and across a wider array of machines, making me think it might be a network/domain issue rather than an issue specific to one machine.

The problem:
Many of the computers on my network experience High Disk Usage (99%) occasionally for seemingly no reason. "System" is always the process that is the culprit. To be a little more exact "many of the computers" means that of the 180 computers on my domain, on any given day 2-5 of them will experience this issue. It is worth noting that it is not always the same 2-5 computers, some days are worse than other, we have around 6 different PC models we have currently in use and our machines run a mixture of Windows 7 Pro, Windows 8.1 Pro, and Windows 10 Pro.

I have attempted individual and specific hotfixes based on suggestions for that particular model, but it always seems to happen again, the hotfixes don't resolve the issue, or in the time it took to fix that computer, 2 more computers were experiencing the same issue. Usually in an hour or two or the next day the computer is back to normal, but we have pretty high demand of our machines so not being able to use a workstation for half a day is pretty detrimental.

Can anyone toss me some ideas of what might potentially cause system wide issues like this? Every workstation uses a VPN to connect to a remote desktop running WIndows Server 2008. The only thing that I can think of is that maybe we have some policies or push updates that are optimized for specific windows version and when we push that it causes undesirable effects for the other versions of windows we have running?

Sorry for being so vague, but this issue seems to not have any rhyme or reason and just randomly causes this issue across a large amount of computers so it is hard to track down, replicate, or try and predict. Thanks in advance!

Comment: run [resource monitor](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/use-resource-monitor-to-monitor-storage-performance/) and look which data the kernel accesses

Comment: I would check to see if there's a hidden botnet running loose.  Not only check the individual computers, but also check outgoing network traffic to see if there's a significant amount of data going to a single domain or IP address.  As another option, your AV may simply be randomly picking PCs to do a full scan.  It may be trying to mask it's signature to hide from the malware it's trying to find by looking like it's the System process...?